# Hardhat send transaction results in: "InvalidArgumentsError: Errors encountered in param 0: Invalid value undefined supplied to : HASH"

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I generated some random adrresses and simply want to impersonate one and send eth between them in a HardHat test:

```
const impersonatedSigner = await ethers.getImpersonatedSigner("0xAE7aE836fDFCcE859103CA8cb8455aE18611b852");
await impersonatedSigner.sendTransaction(
        {
                to: "0x1825FE1AEa79312FFBf44890Fc74DC28DC826386",
                value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
        }
      );
```

However I'm running into an error which is hard to interpret:

> InvalidArgumentsError: Errors encountered in param 0: Invalid value
> undefined supplied to : HASH
> at validateParams (/root/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/jsonrpc/types/input/validation.ts:64:13)
> at EthModule._getTransactionReceiptParams (/root/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:854:26)
> at EthModule.processRequest (/root/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:209:19)
> at HardhatNetworkProvider._send (/root/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:195:31)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (/root/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:118:18)
> at TracerWrapper.request (/root/node_modules/hardhat-tracer/src/wrapper.ts:57:19)
> at EthersProviderWrapper.send (/root/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)

I'm doing this on a forked mainnet but that shouldn't really matter.

Comment: This only happens with an ImpersonatedSigner. With an ethers.getSigners() it works fine.

Comment: It works when impersonating the address `0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890` and `0x6C61f101b6501449908e22818eb934693674ebe9` but not other randomly generated ones AND ones that already exist.